# showing a grid like View on top of a custom View

Tags: android

I want to show up a 3*3 grid like matrix view on top of a custom View.(That custom View is used as a view for displaying a ball acting upon the accelerometer). What I wanted to achieve is when the ball on that custom View is acted upon by accelerometer, it would move along the custom View(which I named "mSimulationView"), passing through any one of the 9 grid like boxes. Passing through any of the boxes(grid) triggers a directional control as that of joypad. I want to make the boxes(grid) visible to the users and also change the color of the box(grid) as the ball passes through it.

The problem is I have no idea about how to add the grid view on top of the custom View. If I add "table Rows" or "Grid Views", it would block the custom View completely. I was thinking of using "GLSurfaceView" for this purpose,but I am not sure if that will work or not either. I am trying to make a gravity Simulated Joypad for android.v2.1.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >           
    </LinearLayout>
```

I need a 3*3 grid like structure on top of the linearLayout.

Comment: why not draw the grid in onDraw of your custom view?

Comment: Thanks that was really useful. I will try and look at the result right now.